# How to import the css file by media queries by condition

Tags: css, media-queries

In my extranel css file, i am trying to load the css using the import... But i unable to import the css files by conditionally...

is there any way to do so?

my try:

```
body {
    background: url(../images/1024/css/bodyBg.jpg);
}
body > section > header{
    background: url(../images/1024/css/headerBg.jpg) top repeat-x;
    height: 93px;
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 5px 0;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    @import url(../styles/sedms.css); // i am not able to import... 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format is

`@import url(../styles/sedms.css) (max-width:768px);`

See here: http://philarcher.org/diary/2011/importrules/